# Magento add to cart price update

Tags: magento, cart

Hello
i want to change magento cart price with the help of height & width of text input. 
EX - the original price of any product is 7.00 $ & when the hight & width is change accordingly i want to add price in original price.
**i want to go for update the cart price .**

Kindly help me..

Comment: You can accept answers to your questions by clicking the checkmark outline next to them. If you do not do this fewer people will feel like answering in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You should make configurable product for this purpose and make width, height are as dropdown attributes of product which help to increase price by changing width,height.
This link will help you
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product/

Enjoy !!!!!!!